# How can I prevent backup for user data in flutter for iOS app?

Tags: ios, security, flutter, storage

The data storage and privacy requirements for the mobile application security verification standard states that 'No sensitive data is included in backups generated by the mobile operating system.'

How do I make sure data is not backed up in my flutter app?

For Android I put

```
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

In AndroidManifest.xml. How can I fix this for iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These folders are backed up to iCloud:

- <AppHome>/Documents
- <AppHome>/Library/Application Support
- <AppHome>/Library/YourDir

iCloud Backup does not copy these temp folders but your data would need to be recreatable:

- <AppHome>/Library/Caches
- <AppHome>/tmp

Otherwise you will need to write some native code and use `isExcludedFromBackupKey`, see https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/